# Query on Trading platforms like X_trader - request for help from code newbie

Tags: programming-languages, enterprise, platform, trading, algorithmic-trading

First up, I'm a software newbie - kindly forgive me if my questions seem naive.

I'm looking to code a broker trading platform like TT's X_trader or CQG's integrated client.

1. Can you please let me know what platforms/languages these are coded on?
2. If I were seeking to remove the fancy stuff and just code the essential functionality(placing & executing orders, essential graphs, easy to use interface), can you provide an estimate of the man-hours it would take, assuming that I can hire the requisite s/w skill sets off the market?
3. Are there open source platforms similar to the above mentioned ones that I can take a look at?

Answer (score 0):

1) TT's X_Trader API provides C#, C++, VB and VBA support while CQG provides support to write strategies in VBA, Visual Basic, C#, C++, and MATLAB. Interactive Brokers is primarily Java. 
However there are certain platforms available in the market that are basically wrappers around different brokers and data providers and they give you a consistent language to work across multiple brokers. Examples are OpenQuant, MetaTrader, Tradestation etc.

2) Its not that simple. There are many questions involved to answer this. Which markets are you going to trade on? What kind of a data feed do you expect if you are generating signals to trade. You can write a simple moving average cross over strategy for daily data dealing with just market orders in pretty much any platform within a day. If the system is complex and you need to handle high volume data updates and make trading decisions based on that, then definitely it'll require more time. Some systems may require upto more than thousand man hours just to build out a trading strategy.

3) I'm not sure if your question refers to open source or free here. There are a few free platforms out there. [Tradelink](http://code.google.com/p/tradelink/) is open source but I believe they don't expose the complete code. [Algo Trader](http://code.google.com/p/algo-trader/) is another example.

Comment: Thanks Aziz. I'm plan to build this for a single exchange (like NSE). I would expect a live feed to be present as the software is intended for registered brokers. High volume data would be transacted. For now, algorithmic trading as such is not being considered. I just want to develop a prototype with an easy to use UI that can be used by brokers to trade high volumes - a bare bones version of the X_trader platform. To clarify, I'm not looking to build functionality of top of platforms like X_trader, I'm trying to develop X_trader itself, but a bare bones version.

Thanks,Mark

Comment: This should be simpler provided that the API you are trying to build on top of provides adequate support for this or a standard FIX communication capability. A simple order placement module should be simple and can be done in a week's development/testing time (again depends on the framework choices etc etc). However modules like price ladder (if you are looking to replicate CQG) can be more complex to develop.